# Cross-origin request blocked Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io

I am trying to make a simple chat room with Socket.IO, but for some reason I keep on getting "Cross-Origin Request Blocked" errors.

[Errors on the chat page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9tS2.png)

Currently I am using the code from https://socket.io/get-started/chat/

Server code:

```javascript
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html.php');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('a user connected');
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('user disconnected');
  });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    console.log('message: ' + msg);
  });
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});

server.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('listening on *:3030');
});
```

HTML code:

```html
<ul id="messages"></ul>
    <form id="form" action="">
        <input id="input" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
    </form>

    <script src="/chat-exmple/node_modules/socket.io/client-dist/socket.io.js"></script>

    <script>
        const socket = io("http://localhost:3030");

        var messages = document.getElementById('messages');
        var form = document.getElementById('form');
        var input = document.getElementById('input');

        form.addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (input.value) {
                socket.emit('chat message', input.value);
                input.value = '';
            }
        });

        socket.on('chat message', function(msg) {
            var item = document.createElement('li');
            item.textContent = msg;
            messages.appendChild(item);
            window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);
        });
    </script>
```

I tried to change the port numbers in the URL and rewriting the code, but I still don’t know what to do to fix this problem.

Comment: see: https://socket.io/docs/v3/handling-cors/ besides you won't need diff ports, use just `io()`, if you have a reverse proxy in front which looks like you do (to forward 3030 to 80), then it will still work. learn about cors, in express it would be as simple as installing cors package and reading thee doc

Answer (score 0):

Do you have already try this?

```
const io = require('socket.io'
(server, {
 cors: {
  origin: '*',
 }
});
```

Comment: Yes. did not work